# Is it possible to not have Mario as your leader?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

For most of the game (that I've experienced so far) you're required to always have Mario as your party leader. While he's a great character, sometimes I'd just much rather not have him in my party. Does this ever happen throughout the story?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to depend on what game mode you are playing.  If you are playing story mode alone, Mario seems to be required in the party.  According to [one GameFAQ](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/211325-mario-rabbids-kingdom-battle/75717411), if you are playing coop, you may choose your leader.

> In the story mode campaign, Mario's always on the team, as he's the team leader. Whenever I play co-op with a friend, it's the two of you working together, and you each choose your own character, so in co-op, you can use anybody and Mario's not restricted.

[Another article](http://kotaku.com/mario-rabbids-kingdom-battle-the-kotaku-review-1798496493) for the game mentions that he cannot be swapped out:

> Mario, who cannot be swapped out of your roster, is more of an all-rounder: he carries a blaster, a hammer, and can stomp on his enemies.

I would try out the coop mode if you have another person to play with, otherwise, it seems like Mario is always going to be there.

Comment: Shame. This is the same conclusion I came to as well, having just tried coop for the first time last night.